# Atom Editor settings for php / drupal indentations

Tags: php, drupal, emacs, editor, atom-editor

Selecting code snippet and hitting Tab button - one of the way to indent sections in the file.

In Emacs editor to achieve such a behaviour https://www.drupal.org/node/59868 these settings are done (keeping in mind Drupal CMS coding standards)

Was not able to achieve similar thing in Atom Editor https://atom.io/

Can anybody guide some way so that i can try doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Auto complete plus](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-plus)?  It seems to have a [snippets](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-snippets) sub-package.